# Hasty / erroneous downvote. Is there undo?

Tags: discussion

There is a question where I hastily downvoted and soon realized I was in error. Is the only recourse to "upvote"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as long as you catch your mistake within five minutes, you can click on the vote arrow again to revert.

If not, your vote is locked (whether up or down doesn't matter). However the vote is only locked until the next time the post is edited at which point you can either undo your previous vote by clicking on the same vote arrow again or even vote the opposite direction.

In the case or mistaken votes on small sites like this one it's considered reasonable to edit the users's post to bring grammar, spelling or formatting improvements yourself just so you can unlock and fix your vote. As long as you aren't using this to change your fickle mind or for other abuses, it's not really a huge concern for us. Because you or somebody has to edit the post and editing bumps the post to the home page there is some level of accountability to make sure somebody isn't trying to play the system.

Comment: Okay, to be clear it was in fact "soon realized" but hasty click attempts at un-doing made me think only other option was +1, not +0. Realized the problem still there many days later.

Answer (score 2):

If you dislike your vote and suspect that no edits will be made to the post. Make an edit to the post and pray your edit is accepted if it is then you can up vote.